# How to replace one tag with another tag in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file as shown below in which I need to replace a tag with another tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>

<result>

    <!-- some xml data along with lot of other tags -->

</result>
```

Now I want this XML to be like this: As you can see `result` tag is replaced with `ClientHolder` tag and everything else within `result` tag is same in `ClientHolder` tag as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>

<ClientHolder xmlns="http://www.host.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.host.com model.xsd">

    <!-- some xml data along with lot of other tags -->

</ClientHolder>
```

Here is my code  so far and after that I am not able to understand how to use Document object to do above stuff:

```
String fileName = location + "/" + "client_" + clientId + ".xml";
File clientFile = new File(fileName);
Document doc = parseXML(clientFile);

// now how to use doc object?
```

Comment: Good question. I don't know your question.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299926/changing-node-name-of-xml-node-with-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the nodes named as result and then modify them all, renaming the node and adding additional attributes:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    doc.renameNode(node, null, "ClientHolder");
    Element element = (Element) node;
    element.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.host.com");
    element.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    element.setAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.host.com model.xsd");
}
```

Here is the imports:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

And this is how you can save it to file:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(clientFile);
Source input = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(input, output);
```